# Swift - Is there a way run a method on an object without calling the object? (Self?)

Tags: swift, refactoring, extension-methods

Quick question on a few different functions I'm having, all have the same idea. I have an object, and I want to run a function with it. But because it's an extension of the Objects type, I'm calling the `object.method(on: object)`. Is there a way to simplify this so that it runs on itself without having to state it?

Example:

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {
    
    func removeBackButtonString(on navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
    
}
```

Used in Code:

```
navigationController?.removeBackButtonString(on: navigationController!)
```

But is there a way to call it like so?

```
navigationController?.removeBackButtonString()
```

Or, to extended a NSManagedObject:

```
extension Object {
    func setFavorite(object: Object) {
        object.isFavorite = true
    }
}
```

Use: `object.setFavorite(object: object)` But how can you tap into the `object` properties if you don't have the parameter?
Example: `object.setFavorite()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can modify your extension function to something like this:

```
extension UINavigationController {        
    func removeBackButtonString() {
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        // `self` is inferred in Swift
        navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
}
```

Then, this will run perfectly fine:

```
navigationController?.removeBackButtonString()
```

**Update**: The same applies also to your second example:

```
extension Object {
    func setFavorite() {
        isFavorite = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Is that also the case for NSManagedObjects? Same idea as above, but instead of changing the backButton on a NavVC, a property on the object?

Comment: @StonedStudio yes, that's the purpose of extensions. To "extend" the functionality of a type.

Comment: I know. I'm just not sure if its possible to do the same for other things. Like the mentioned NSManagedObject. I edited an another example, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tap into it.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out - I was naming the properties wrong.